# SetValue with generic type T

Tags: c#, reflection, instance, generic-type-argument

I have this function:
the variable `c` obtains all the properties of my class `<T>`
in this case:

`c` ->
`Id`
`Key`
`Value`

```
public List<T> ReadStoreProceadure<T>(string storeName)
{
    var result = new List<T>();
    var instance = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T), new object[] {});
    var c = typeof (T);
    var data = DataReader.ReadStoredProceadures(_factibilidad, storeName); // This part is returning verified data and it's ok

    while (data.Read())
    {
        if (data.HasRows)
        {
            foreach (var item in c.GetProperties())
            {
                //item.SetValue(c, item.Name, null);
            }
        }
    }     
}
```

How I can add these values to my instance `instance` and add it to my `result` variable?
It's possible?

Comment: I think you would be way better off constraining T to be of some interface/abstract class that has those 3 fields on it.

Comment: This may help http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/784090/Conversion-Between-DataTable-and-List-in-Csharp

Comment: @pquest I'm not sure if I can build an abstact type, because I have `n` number of models with different format. But I can merge all of those models in a generic `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>` I think

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created an extension method for `IDataReader` that does essentially what I believe you're trying to do:

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IDataReader dr) where T: new()
{
    var col = new List<T>();
    var type = typeof(T);
    var props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        var obj = new T();
        for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            string fieldName = dr.GetName(i);
            var prop = props.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToLower() == fieldName.ToLower());
            if (prop != null)
            {
                if (dr[i] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    prop.SetValue(obj, dr[i], null);
                }
            }
        }
        col.Add(obj);
    }

    dr.Close();
    return col;
}
```

However, you'll notice I've chosen to work the from the other way around. Instead of iterating the type's properties and fetching them from the DataReader, I iterate the DataReader columns and check for a matching property on the type. You should be able to quickly modify this to fit your data retrieval scheme.